# Tagging specific data from an .xlsx file when importing a data frame to R

Tags: r, excel

[excel file with marked data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQqp9.png)

Referencing the picture linked above, I'm looking to import this excel file into R, but I'd like the data that are red and have the strikethrough to be tagged/marked somehow in R - in order to be able to create vectors from them. Is there a way to do that, without having to rearrange the data frame first?

Comment: Please set out what coding you have tried so far. This link may be useful so that you can help us to help you [mre]

Comment: If possible, try to add your data as text. It is easier to reproduce in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The **openxlsx** package has the ability to access the workbook style. Among much other information, it reads the following from the worksheets:

- Cell formatting
- Font name
- Font size
- Font colour

However, it doesn't have the "strikethrough effect". But you can certainly take advantage of the different font colours.

Suppose you have the following Excel file where I've made two cells red with a strikethrough effect and kept the others as normal:

[image]

Load the library and import the data.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("filename.xlsx")
data <- read.xlsx(wb, colNames=FALSE)
```

The styles are contained in the `styleObjects` object

```
wb$styleObjects
[[1]]
[[1]]$style
A custom cell style. 

 Cell formatting: GENERAL 
 Font name: Calibri 
 Font size: 11 
 Font colour: #FF0000 

[[1]]$sheet
[1] "Sheet1"

[[1]]$rows
[1] 3 4

[[1]]$cols
[1] 2 3
```

There may be many other elements of the list depending on the number of custom styles you applied to the cells in your worksheet. Each custom style will be included in this object. Here I've only got 1 custom style corresponding to the red font colour (#FF0000). The $rows and $cols items give the row and column indices of only the cells that have this font colour. You can then use this information to extract the required data values.

```
red.rows <- wb$styleObjects[[1]]$rows
red.cols <- wb$styleObjects[[1]]$cols

data[cbind(red.rows, red.cols)]
#[1] 43 12
```